How could I toggle modifier keys (Cmd, Ctrl, Opt, etc.) instead of holding them down, like the caps lock?
I looked at Sticky Keys in settings but it only stays down for one keystroke, I want to keep the modifier keys held down.
Basically, I want to toggle modifier keys on and off like how caps lock works.
For instance, if I press Cmd then it stays pressed down on macOS (toggled on), so if I press a letter like H after that, it does Cmd+H, and if I press Cmd again then the key will stop being held (toggled off). I really wanna try this out because it actually takes a split second longer to press hotkeys with modifiers because you have to make sure the modifier(s) are held down before pressing non-modifier keys.
I'd also like to use Esc to toggle off all modifiers, after using hotkeys with multiple modifiers.

I think it can be done by using some sort of modifier keys tap to detect modifier keys, then intercept the keys and send the modifier+X events
